# How would I write VBA code to save an excel workbook with the filename as a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that will change weekly and I wanted to write a script that would save the workbook in a set location and change the name to what ever the start date of the week was.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if I am not being clear, I shall try and explain it better.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `Recording a Macro` and saving the Workbook with the name you need? This should generate the necessary code

Comment: Why not making a minimal effort to search for a solution before posting on SO ? SO is here to help you solve programming issues, not laziness issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [`Workbook.SaveAs`-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx). The page I linked to explain what the different arguments you pass to the function do, the most pertinent one for you is the first one, `Filename`, which you can set to be equal to just about any string (such as one retrieved from a cell). You can also (optionally) include a filepath preceding the filename, to determine where the file is saved, otherwise it is saved to the current folder.

Comment: I keep getting the error "Application defined or object defined error" my code is

   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="E:\Weekly Hours\" & Cells.Item(4, B), FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: There's probably just a problem with the syntax (e.g. you can't use the range-qualifier `Cells.Item(4,B)`, I think. Switching things around a bit, this short macro works for me: `Sub test()
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\a2*****\Documents\Excelark\" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B4"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
`

Answer (score 0):

```
Workbook.SaveAs(FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)
```

You can assign the path and the file name to `FileName` as String

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm